# how to lock iPad orientation for loading only?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have an iPad app, I need it to load in ladnscapeLeft mode at all times during loading, after wards it can rotate and respond to orientation changes and go to any other orientation. How can I accomplish that? 
I tried changing the plist.info file to have only landscapeleft, but that locks that orientation through out the life cycle of the app.

So to clarify, the app should only load in ladnscapeLeft, once loading is complete, it can respond to other orienations.

Comment: If the rest of your app supports all orientations, then your loading screen should too. What's the reason you can't support portrait modes during loading?

Answer (score -1):

You'll need to override the `UIViewController` rotation events. Here's an example:

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    if (appDelegate.topViewController != nil) {
        return [appDelegate.topViewController supportedInterfaceOrientations];
    } else {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
    }
}
- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    if (appDelegate.topViewController != nil) {
        return [appDelegate.topViewController preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation];
    } else {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
    }
}
```